# Give absolute url address

Tags: html, path

I'm trying to understand absolute and relative Url addresses; however, when I attempted an exercise, I couldn't solve it. Here is the exercise:

Given the following URL address `http://www.unsite.org/a/b/index.html` , the document `index.html` contains 3 relatives URL addresses: 
`<img src="../logo.png" alt="Logo de l’entreprise"/> //Line 1
<img src="/images/logo.png" alt="Logo de l’entreprise"/>  //Line 2
<img src="images/logo.png" alt="Logo de l’entreprise"/> //Line 3`

Give the corresponding absolute URL of each of them. -__-. 
Can someone also explain the difference between `Line 2` and `Line 3`?

I understand that (for line 2 and 3 ) `logo.png` is in the folder `images` which is in the same directory as `index.html`. For  `Line 1` logo.png is in the parent folder of `index.html` and that's pretty much it I understand but I still don't know how to solve this exercise.

Comment: A preceding `/` means the root directory. So for line two, it's `http://www.unsite.org/images...`

Comment: Lines 2 and 3 are not in the same place at all.  One is relative to the root of the domain, one is relative to the current "folder".

Comment: THANKS for all the answer!! Thanks a lot, sadly i can only check one answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Line 2** `<img src="/images/logo.png" alt="Logo de l’entreprise"/>` will attempt to load the image from the path defined **relative to your root web directory**.

**Example:** If your domain name is www.yourwebsite.com and the current web page is www.yourwebsite.com/folder/page.html, then it will attempt to load the image from **http://www.yourwebsite.com/images/logo.png**

**Line 3** `<img src="images/logo.png" alt="Logo de l’entreprise"/>` will attempt to load the image **relative to the current directory** of the web page.

**Example:** If your domain name is www.yourwebsite.com and the current web page is www.yourwebsite.com/folder/page.html, then it will attempt to load the image from **http://www.yourwebsite.com/folder/images/logo.png**

Answer (score 1):

Given `http://www.unsite.org/a/b/index.html`:

```
<img src="../logo.png" alt="Logo de l’entreprise"/> //Line 1

http://www.unsite.org/a/logo.png


<img src="/images/logo.png" alt="Logo de l’entreprise"/>  //Line 2

http://www.unsite.org/images/logo.png


<img src="images/logo.png" alt="Logo de l’entreprise"/> //Line 3

http://www.unsite.org/a/b/images/logo.png
```

Answer (score 0):

Line 2 has `/` in front of, so that means "start from the root of the web host" absolute URL will be `http://www.unsite.org/images/logo.png`

Line 3 hasn't `/`in front so it should start from the current url looking the complete path, absolute URL will be  `http://www.unsite.org/a/b/images/logo.png`

Answer (score 0):

If you have a chance, take a look at those lines while you have the deployment folder open in front of you in a windows explorer or finder program.

I think this is your folder structure.

```
ROOT
|----images/logo.png (line2)
|----a
|    |-----b
|    |     |----index.html
|    |     |----images/logo.png (line3)
|    |
|    |---logo.png (line 1)
```

index.html is in root/a/b/ folder.

As you can see, there is an images folder in the same location where index.html resides and that images folder holds logo.png file (line 3)

Parent folder of b is folder a. This is where another logo.png file is. (line 1)

And finally there is another images folder at the root. And there is also another logo.png in there. (line 2)

Same names everywhere makes thinks more complicated than it actually us. Renaming each one and fixing the HTML file may help you understand it better. Cheers.